# App doesn't respond while converting an image to a grayscale image

Tags: java, android, multithreading, image, image-processing

I'm trying to developing an app that could apply some of the basic effects on existing images. I was going pretty much O.K with it. But when I came to play with pixels, it stopped working. Can someone help me out with it? Should I use another thread instead of main thread for writing the following code?

```
         int[] imagePixels = new int[picWidth * picHeight];
         bitmap.getPixels(imagePixels, 0, picWidth, 0, 0, picWidth, picHeight);


         for (int y = 0; y < picHeight; y++) {

             for (int x = 0; x < picWidth; x++) {

                 int index = y * picWidth + x;
                 int red = (imagePixels[index] >> 16) & 0xff;     
                 int green = (imagePixels[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                 int blue = imagePixels[index] & 0xff;

                 red = (int) Math.abs(red-255);
                 green = (int) Math.abs(green-255);
                 blue = (int) Math.abs(blue-255);

                 imagePixles[index] = 0xff000000 | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;

                 }
        }
        bitmap.setPixels(imagePixels, 0, picWidth, 0, 0, picWidth, picHeight);
```

Comment: What does "it stopped working" mean? Please be more explicit.

Comment: Should I use another thread instead of main thread for writing the following code? > yes

Comment: @Egor Android says to me that my app is not responding with two options of Wait and Cancel.

Comment: @Rajawa I've to apply more than 20 effects in my app. How would I know when to put the code on separate thread?

Comment: How large is the image?

Comment: because you are working on the ui thread. don't.

Comment: @ChrisCooper it is 480 by 320

Comment: OK, well the image is not massive (if you had said 480K by 320K it would have been a different matter).
As I said in my answer, it looks like you are using the dispatch thread when you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing GUI code (AWT/Swing/etc.) the first rule is never do anything CPU intensive in the dispatch thread.

If you are responding to user input - like a mouse click, touch or a menu selection - and you plan to do something that will take up a lot of processor time, spin off a separate thread to do the work, and submit an event to the event queue when the job is complete.

That way the UI is responsive, and will respond to user generated events and programatically generated events when you want to refresh parts of the display after you have applied your effects.

This is general advice for any UI coding, someone may be able to add more regarding Android specific functionality; my guess is that the Android OS is not getting a response to events it is injecting into the event processing queue, and therefore assumes your app is dead, when in fact it is alive, just busy doing something in the dispatch thread when it shouldn't be.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 in Android we have helper AsyncTask class (Thread + Handler)... but generally - true ...